# fontawesome в Заголовке браузера

Tags: css, fontawesome

Поставил на сайт шрифт fontawesome поставил иконки в названиях категорий но возник вопрос: в браузерной строке он не отображается как надо - вместо него пустой квадрат - вопрос: есть ли способ настроить отображение иконки в браузерной строке?

Comment: никак, там системный шрифт

Comment: Спасибо большое.